# How to navigate after callling async web method completed?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7

Im working on a windows phone application using a webservice.

I would like to navigate to an other page after completed a webmethod call.
I have no idea about how it can be possible.

Here is a part of my view behing code:

> ```
> private void Button1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         this._ws.InitializeConnexion("my name");
>         this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/profile.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
>     }
> ```

And here is my view model class:

> ```
> public sealed class MobileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
> {
>    private WSClient _ws;
>    private T_member _member;
>    public T_member Member
>    {
>        get
>        {
>            return _member;
>        }
>        set
>        {
>            _member = value;
>            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Member");
>        }
>    }
>    public MobileViewModel()
>    {
>         _ws = new WSMobileClient();
>         _ws.InitializeConnexionCompleted += new EventHandler<InitializeConnexionCompletedEventArgs>(_ws_InitializeConnexionCompleted);
>    }
>    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
>    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
>    {
>         PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
>         if (propertyChanged != null)
>         {
>             propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
>         }
>    }
>    public void InitializeConnexion(string name)
>    {
>        _ws.InitializeConnexionAsync(name);
>    }
>    private void _ws_InitializeConnexionCompleted(object sender, InitializeConnexionCompletedEventArgs e)
>    {
>        if (e.Error == null)
>        {
>            this.Member = e.Result;
>        }
>        else
>        {
>            MessageBox.Show("error.");
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

Does anyone can help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can do this. A couple of suggestions:

1) Use an ICommand and bind it to your button not the code behind. This puts that logic in your viewmodel where it belongs. [Here's one example of how to do that](http://johnpapa.net/5-simple-steps-to-commanding-in-silverlight). [And another](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2009/12/02/using-icommand-silverlight-4.aspx).

2) Once you have that logic in your viewmodel then you can orchestrate navigiation with your connection status without needing to pass messages back to the view. Something like:

```
 private void _ws_InitializeConnexionCompleted(object sender, InitializeConnexionCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            this.Member = e.Result;
            this.Navigate("/View/profile.xaml");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error.");
        }
    }
}

protected void Navigate(string address)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
          return;

    Uri uri = new Uri(address, UriKind.Relative);
    Debug.Assert(App.Current.RootVisual is PhoneApplicationFrame);
    ((PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(uri);            
}
```

Comment: The ICommand looks quite interesting. But, I have no visibility of the NavigationService from my ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your additionnal code. I tried this but I got an App.Current.RootVisual null. How it is possible ?

Comment: What does your App.Xaml.cs look like? If it's the one created by the project wizard you should see somthing like:         // Do not add any additional code to this method
        private void CompleteInitializePhoneApplication(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the root visual to allow the application to render
            if (RootVisual != RootFrame)
                RootVisual = RootFrame;

            // Remove this handler since it is no longer needed
            RootFrame.Navigated -= CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;
        }

Comment: Finally It works well! Its a easy way to navigate by just adding one method. Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

I would pass in a continuation lambda to the method that is triggering the web method call - the continuation is then executed when the call has been successfully completed:

```
private void Button1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   InitializeConnexion("my name", () => 
   {
       this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/profile.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   });
}
```

You can store this as `Action` in the `MobileViewModel` class.

```
   Action _webCallCompletedAction;
   public void InitializeConnexion(string name, Action action)
   {
       webCallCompletedAction = action;
       _ws.InitializeConnexionAsync(name);
   }
```

and finally execute it after your web service all is completed:

```
private void _ws_InitializeConnexionCompleted(object sender, 
                                              InitializeConnexionCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Error != null)
       {
           this.Member = e.Result;
           webCallCompletedAction(); 
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("error.");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. It's one other way to navigate from the ViewModel. With your solution, we can passe the Uri from the View code behind, it could be better.